# App Service App Setting Not Being Overwritten

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to get an extremely basic example working to get App Settings overwritten (as a starting point).
I've created a new web app from a template, using .Net Core 6. The only change is that I've added a setting as shown below:

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "TestSetting": "TestValue"
}
```

I've got this hooked into an App Service app, with an app setting like follows:[image]

I expect that the TestSetting value will be TestValue3. When I look in Kudu, I see the appsettings.json hasn't been changed at all.

I've been working on this for a while. Everything I see online tells me that this should work. The app displays as expected, it's just that the App Setting is never getting overwritten.

Edit: Someone asked for the program.cs file, so here it is. I haven't changed it from the default.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Please share your `Program.cs` file.

Comment: The `appsettings.json` file will not be updated.Try to display the value, you can see the updated value.

Comment: The value from the `Configuration` section `App Settings` will be displayed. The `appsettings.json` file remains unchanged in KUDU console.

Comment: My understanding is that you don't need to use the value in your app, it should detect the appsettings.json and replace the values. Are you saying that it detects which values are being used? (Also, added the program.cs)

Comment: You can see the updated value in `KUDU Console` => `Environment` => `App Settings`.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6em68.png)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. It doesn't actually update the file as visible in the file system, it only shows under Environment. Thanks. If you post an answer to that effect, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes,sure will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override any `App setting` value, then the key has to be set in the `appsettings.json` file (with dummy value).

- Same key name has to be set in `Azure Configuration Application Settings` with the desired value.

[image]

When we set the keys in `Azure App settings` the specified key values will be overridden with the `appsettings.json` file values.

- If the values are not set, the same values which are in `appsettings.json` will be taken.

> When I look in Kudu, I see the appsettings.json hasn't been changed at all.

There will be no change in the deployed `appsettings.json`.

The updated values can be seen in `KUDU Console` => `Environment` => `App Settings`.

[image]

***Display the value in `.cshtml` file:***

When the application is run locally, the values from `appsettings.json` will be taken.

***Index.cshtml :***

```cs
@inject IConfiguration configuration
<h1 class="display-4">App Setting Value - @configuration["TestSetting"]</h1
```

***Local Output:***

[image]

- For the deployed `Azure App service`, the values are taken from the Azure App Settings.

***Deployed App Output:***

[image]

Comment: Very well explained, thanks.